# Improvement on database schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle

[image: pet store database schema]

I'm creating a small pet shop database for a project

The database needs to have a list of products by supplier that can be grouped by pet type or product category.

Each in store sale and customer order can have multiple products per order and an employee attached to them the customer order must be have a customer and employee must have a position,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLNy7.jpg

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TheEwook I think the question is obvious, he wants a suggestion on how he can improve his schema

Comment: @James - I can't see anything in the image

Comment: Provide link to fullsize image please

Comment: hopefully this is bigger

[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/n5j8xrj.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

Here are some random thoughts

1. I often separate addresses from the thing that has an address.  You could make 1-many relationships between Employee, Customer and Supplier to an address table.  That would allow you to have different types of addresses per entity, and to change addresses without touching the original table.
2. If it is possible for prices to change for an item, you would need to account for that somehow.  Ideas there are create a pricing table, or to capture the price on the sales item table.
3. I don't like the way you handle the sales item table.  the different foreign keys based on the type of the transaction is not quite correct.  An alternative would be to replace SalesItem SaleID and OrderId with the SalesRecordId...  another better option would be to just merge the fields from InStoreSale, SalesRecord, and CustomerOrders into a single table and slap an indicator on the table to indicate which type of transaction it was.
4. You would probably try to be consistent with plurality on your tables.  For example, CustomerOrders vs. CustomerOrder.
5. Putting PositionPay on the EmployeePosition table seems off to...  Employees in the same position typically can have different pay.
6. Is the PetType structured with enough complexity?  Can't you have items that apply to more than one pet type?  For example, a fishtank can be used for fish or lizards?  If so, you will need a many-to-many join table there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks im going to make some changes and come back to you,

The idea of SalesRecord was to be able to Produce sales report for a daily/weekly/monthly period would it still not be needed for that?

Comment: I don't think you need a special table to support reporting...  Unless you have some performance or auditing related need to store the results of the reports...  and if you need that, I'd probably approach that differently.  by the way, if you like the answer, would you mind accepting it?  I have a personal goal to  establish a rep here ;)

Comment: Thanks accepted your answer

I updated the design let me know what you think, im still not sure on how i can improve the sales part

http://i.imgur.com/EQ2rflB.png

Comment: checkmark accepts the answer :). 1. don't see much use in splitting the city/country tables, not incorrect to do so. 2. You made the plural issue worse with cities, countries, and couriers. 3. Orders tables work better now. 4. The stock item cross reference tables look to be grown up now... assuming you need it. Consider renaming them to ItemPetType and ItemCategory. 5. if you added a column to CustomerOrder named IsInStore as a boolean, you could ditch the InStoreSale table entirely, and also ditch SalesDetails.CustomerOrderId. 6. order.couriername s/b the id not the name